# Error loading a file in a ros node in a git repository

Tags: python, git, file, ros

I am trying to load a model in pytorch in my rosnode.
I have used the exact same command in a different python file, and there it worked(k is an int):

```
model = torch.load("01.Actual/02.NeuralNetwork/02.PaperNetworks/saved_model" + str(k) + ".pt")
```

But using the exact same command, Ros tells me:

> ERROR] [1682584228.090341]: bad callback: <function useData at 0x7fba173da280>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
> cb(msg)
> File "/home/demaisch/git/ros_workspaces/demaisch_ws/ros/src/my_dsp/scripts/data_to_modell.py", line 49, in useData
> model = torch.load("01.Actual/02.NeuralNetwork/02.PaperNetworks/saved_model" + str(k) + ".pt")
> File "/home/demaisch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 791, in load
> with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
> File "/home/demaisch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 271, in _open_file_like
> return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
> File "/home/demaisch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 252, in **init**
> super().**init**(open(name, mode))
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '01.Actual/02.NeuralNetwork/02.PaperNetworks/saved_models0.pt'

I used the same command, just that I am now in a folder inside a git repository, while the file is still outside of the git repository on my pc. Also, I want to load it in a ros node instead of directly as a python code.
Does this make any difference?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to share the rest of your code. The error isn't directly because of the line you shared. Looks like you're trying to use something as a subscriber callback that isn't valid.